# Closing activity should kill app even from background

Tags: android

I am creating only one activity of the app. And want that while closing the activity the app should also be removed from the background.

```
openIntent = new Intent(context, WebActivity.class);
            openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(openIntent);
```

I have tied many ways but every time the app stays in the background.

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
finishAffinity();
```

I am using a background service. It is a video call activity like WhatsApp. So when the notification from firebase comes then I have to start calling activity. If the user presses the cancels call button then I have to kill the activity like on WhatsApp. But by using the above code keep the app in the background

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line for exit app**

```
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        finishAffinity();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
```

**And also replace this flag with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**

*Note: Check background service not available in your app*

Comment: I am using a background service. It is a video call activity like WhatsApp. So when the notification from firebase comes then I have to start calling activity. If the user presses the cancels call button then I have to kill the activity like on WhatsApp. But by using the above code keep the app in the background.